# Make an Object global in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, rootscope

In plain javascript, I can group similar functions into an object like so:

```
var Monolog = {

  notify: function(title, message) {

      // Do something with title and message
    },

  confirm: function(title, message, func) {

      // Do something with title, message and func
    }
}
```

Which I can access like so:

```
Monolog.notify('Error', 'Error message');
```

Now, using AngularJS, I need the functions inside Monolog to change a $scope.variable, which mean that I would either have to use service or the rootScope.

How would I do this?

Comment: It seems that you answered by your own question in the last sentence i.e. use a service or put the variable in `$rootScope`

Comment: are you asking how to write an angular service? *don't* use `$rootScope` for this, that is a fundamental misunderstanding of how `$rootScope` works.  Beyond that, "Global" is never good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service is the better choice. You should try to use services over the 
`$rootScope` because they make the code more reusable and readable. Also using the global scope is bad idea in most cases.

Changing your `$scope.variable` can be accomplished by a setter and a getter in a service.

**EDIT**

And also as **@Adrian** added:

> Services (which are injectable) improve testability

Comment: And the services (which are injectable) improve testability.

Comment: I agree with Hristo. I did have to make a value globally accessible in the same sense as borislemke describes simply because it was seen as being easier to access than injecting a service, disregarding testing. It was accessible from anywhere via $root.

Comment: @AdrianMitev I've read somewhere else that it's not a good practice to change a $scope inside a service. What if I had and alert box sitting in my app that needs to change a value whenever an $http request has been done? Lets say, in my code example I need to update $scope.alertTitle after an $http call?

Comment: I was hoping to get an explicit answer but after fiddling around a bit I finally understand the concept. Thanks!